# Adding additional custom data to Azure AD Log Analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am currently streaming my Azure AD sign-in logs to Log Analytics (as described in [this MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-integrate-activity-logs-with-log-analytics#send-logs-to-azure-monitor)). I also have a separate Azure Function that retrieves all Users from Graph API, performs some lookup operations, and creates a "CompanyTeam" value for each user. The Function runs once per day.

My goal is to combine the AAD sign-in Logs Analytics with the "CompanyTeam" data, so that I can perform queries like `SigninLogs | join kind=inner CompanyTeam on UserPrincipalName`

1. What is the best storage option for Azure Function outputting User+CompanyTeam data? It is a daily refresh that overwrites previous values.
2. How do I connect that storage option to the existing AAD Sign-in Log Analytics workspace?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: For `azure function`, you should enable `application insights` as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-application-insights-integration). Then in `azure log analytics`, you can use the [cross query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query) to join `application insights`.

Comment: If you haven't enabled `application insights` for `azure function`, then you can [create a new application insights with azure log analytics enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource#create-workspace-based-resource), then all the data from `azure functions` will flow into that `azure log analytics`.

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks:).

Answer (score 0):

For `azure function`, you should enable `application insights` as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-application-insights-integration). Then in `azure log analytics` or `application insights`, you can use the [cross query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query) to join the related `application insights` or `azure log analytics`.

Another solution is that, you can [create a new application insights with azure log analytics enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource#create-workspace-based-resource)(here, the `azure log analytics` is the `existing AAD Sign-in Log Analytics workspace`), then all the data from azure functions will flow into that `azure log analytics`. Next, you can write a proper query to fetch the data.

Please let me know if you have any questions.